# Perl unexpected result

Tags: perl, parameter-passing

Imagine I have this Perl script

```
my $name = "   foo    ";
my $sn   = "     foosu";

trim($name, \$sn);

print "name: [$name]\n";
print "sn: [$sn]\n";
exit 0;


sub trim{

   my $fref_trim = sub{
                          my ($ref_input) = @_;
                          ${$ref_input} =~ s/^\s+// ;
                          ${$ref_input} =~ s/\s+$// ;
    };

   foreach my $input (@_){
       if (ref($input) eq "SCALAR"){
            $fref_trim->($input);
       } else {
            $fref_trim->(\$input);
       }
   }
}
```

Result:

```
name: [foo]
sn: [foosu]
```

I would expect $name to be "`[   foo    ]`" when printing the value after calling `trim`, but the sub is setting `$name` as I would want it. Why is this working, when it really shouldn't?

I'm not passing $name by reference and the `trim` sub is not returning anything. I'd expect the `trim` sub to create a copy of the `$name` value, process the copy, but then the original `$name` would still have the leading and trailing white spaces when printed in the main code.

I assume it is because of the alias with `@_`, but shouldn't the `foreach my $input (@_)` force the sub to copy the value and only treat the value not the alias?

I know I can simplify this sub and I used it only as an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elements of `@_` are aliases to the original variables. What you are observing is the difference between:

```
sub ltrim {
    $_[0] =~ s/^\s+//;
    return $_[0];
}
```

and

```
sub ltrim {
    my ($s) = @_;
    $s =~ s/^\s+//;
    return $s;
}
```

Compare your code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $name = "   foo    ";
my $sn   = "     foosu";

trim($name, \$sn);

print "name: [$name]\n";
print "sn: [$sn]\n";

sub trim {
    my @args = @_;

    my $fref_trim = sub{
        my ($ref_input) = @_;
        ${$ref_input} =~ s/^\s+//;
        ${$ref_input} =~ s/\s+\z//;
    };

   for my $input (@args) {
       if (ref($input) eq "SCALAR") {
           $fref_trim->($input);
       }
       else {
           $fref_trim->(\$input);
       }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./zz.pl
name: [   foo    ]
sn: [foosu]
```

Note also that the loop variable in `for my $input ( @array )` does not create a new copy for each element of the array. See `perldoc perlsyn`:

> The `foreach` loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the scalar variable `VAR` to be each element of the list in turn. ...
>
> ...
>
> the `foreach` loop index variable is an implicit alias for each item in the list that you're looping over.

In your case, this would mean that, at each iteration `$input` is an alias to the corresponding element of `@_` which itself is an alias to the variable that was passed in as an argument to the subroutine.

Making a copy of `@_` thus prevents the variables in the calling context from being modified. Of course, you could do something like:

```
sub trim {
    my $fref_trim = sub{
        my ($ref_input) = @_;
        ${$ref_input} =~ s/^\s+//;
        ${$ref_input} =~ s/\s+\z//;
    };

   for my $input (@_) {
       my $input_copy = $input;
       if (ref($input_copy) eq "SCALAR") {
           $fref_trim->($input_copy);
       }
       else {
           $fref_trim->(\$input_copy);
       }
   }
}
```

but I find making a wholesale copy of `@_` once to be clearer and more efficient assuming you do not want to be selective.

Comment: I think you're answering the wrong question here. The OP says *"I assume it is because of the alias with `@_`, but shouldn't the `foreach my $input (@_)` force the sub to copy the value and only treat the value not the alias?"* and so appears to know that `@_` contains aliases to the actual parameters, but not that the control variable of a `for` loop is also an alias.

Comment: @Borodin Tried to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume it is because of the alias with `@_`, but shouldn't the `foreach my $input (@_)` force the sub to copy the value and only treat the value not the alias?

You're right that `@_` contains aliases. The part that's missing is that `foreach` also aliases the loop variable to the current list element. Quoting [`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

> If any element of LIST is an lvalue, you can modify it by modifying VAR inside the loop. Conversely, if any element of LIST is NOT an lvalue, any attempt to modify that element will fail. In other words, the `foreach` loop index variable is an implicit alias for each item in the list that you're looping over.

So ultimately `$input` is an alias for `$_[0]`, which is an alias for `$name`, which is why you see the changes appearing in `$name`.